# Do dynamically compiled files use csc.exe in .NET?

Tags: asp.net, .net, jit, csc

Title asked it all,

Do dynamically compiled files, such as .cshtml files, use csc.exe in .NET?

I saw this question [C# JIT compiling and .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589409/c-sharp-jit-compiling-and-net)

But it doesn't fully go into the compilation of a dynamic file to before being Jit'ed.

So you have this site https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx.
Which says:

> By default, ASP.NET Web pages and code files are compiled dynamically
>   when users first request a resource, such as an ASP.NET page (.aspx
>   file), from a Web site. After pages and code files have been compiled
>   the first time, the compiled resources are cached, so that subsequent
>   requests to the same page are extremely efficient.

So am I to understand that csc.exe runs on first request of a new resource before being JIT'ed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer appears to be yes.

- Source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/05/12/enabling-the-net-compiler-platform-roslyn-in-asp-net-applications/

"the Roslyn compiler would be loaded into memory, improving greatly performance for not pre-compiled websites with multiple .asx/*.cshtml files. The new version, however, features a new /bin/roslyn/csc.exe file, which is executed once per file, completely removing the mentioned above optimization feature"