# Does the C# compiler optimize out an empty try/catch?

Tags: c#, compiler-optimization

In c#, how much time is expended in an empty try catch block?

I've heard that it is between 10-55ms, but i'm leaning to zero/one as the compiler will replace the empty try catch with a no-op placeholder.

any compiler experts that can verify this information?

Comment: I believe the reason that you're getting so many downvotes is that this probably isn't the appropriate place to ask this particular question...

Comment: You can review the generated IL/bytecode yourself. [How can I view MSIL / CIL generated by C# compiler? Why is it called assembly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326571/how-can-i-view-msil-cil-generated-by-c-sharp-compiler-why-is-it-called-assemb)

Comment: Make sure to choose a good title, it really helps avoid negative initial reactions/votes. The hypothesis and fundamental question that has been presented is "I'm leaning to zero/one as the compiler will replace the empty try catch with a no-op placeholder.", so focus on that.

Comment: When you say "empty try catch block", do you mean if you _literally_ have: `try { } catch { }`?

Comment: what's the real world application of this question?

Comment: Jonesy- there is no real world application...  it is more of a "what does the c# compiler do in this instance" question.    Chris- yup a literally empty try catch.  jfabs- why do you feel this is not the right place for this type of question?  It has to deal 100% with coding, it deals with the very fundamentals of programming and optimization.    SO really needs to implement a ban on anonymous downvotes....   they are non constructive and alienates people, thus enforcing the elitism that is currently hurting apple.

Comment: @pithhelmet: Then yes, if compiler optimizations are turned on, the compiler will ignore the try/catch. With optimizations turned off (i.e., "debug mode"), then it will emit the IL instructions for debugging purposes.

Comment: @pithhelmet Didn't downvote, but if you think that you could elaborate on what you mean when you say "SO really needs to implement a ban on anonymous downvotes", may I suggest posting it on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ ?

Comment: jdphenix - i did post over there...  and did i ever get flamed...  it was like 300 down votes for asking the question....   but thanks for the reply

Comment: @pithhelmet It almost seemed like a bit more theory oriented but I'll give it to you that it is code based.  I would still have to recommend that you included something code-specific like what you had tried to suit your question.  It is interesting though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If when you say "empty try catch block", you mean *literally*:

```
try
{
}
catch
{
}
```

Then yes, when building *with compiler optimizations turned on* (that is, "release" mode), it will not emit any IL instructions. For example:

```
private void Test()
{
    try
    {
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Compiles to:

```
IL_0000:  ret
```

Which is the same as if it were an empty method.

However, when optimizations are turned *off* (that is, "debug" mode), it emits:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  nop         
IL_0002:  nop         
IL_0003:  leave.s     IL_000A
IL_0005:  pop         
IL_0006:  nop         
IL_0007:  nop         
IL_0008:  leave.s     IL_000A
IL_000A:  nop         
IL_000B:  ret
```

Whereas an empty method would be:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ret
```

Whether or not these IL instructions are stripped when the *JIT* compiler is executed, I am not positive. But this would still only apply when compiling without compiler optimizations as with them turned on the try/catch is stripped out during the initial compile to IL before it hits the JIT compiler.

EDIT: I just realized I may not have actually answered *the* question:

In *release mode*, zero time is expended on an empty try/catch.
In *debug mode*, a non-zero time is expended on an empty try/catch as it still emits the necessary IL code for debugging/breakpoint purposes and requires *some* JIT compilation. However, it would be a **negligibly small** amount of time. Definitely nowhere near the neighbourhood of "10-55 milliseconds".

Answer (score 2):

If you check compiled code by proper software (like ILspy or Reflector), you can see that empty block will be deleted completley by compiler.

[image: ILSpy image]

Comment: In the future, you'll want to back up your answers with sources and such

Comment: @Jfabs check this http://prntscr.com/30ielc  (i hope i get this question right, because name of topic is pretty confsing)

Comment: looks like you are correct to me.  Thank you for following up.  I would recommend you edit your post to include that screenshot as evidence of your statement.