# Is the Null-Conditional operator optimized across consecutive usages sites or does it result in duplicate checks?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

Does using the null-conditional operator duplicate null checks?  For example

```
var x = instance?.Property1;
var y = instance?.Property2;
```

Does that get compiled into this:

```
if (instance != null)
{
  var x = instance.Property1;
  var y = instance.Property2;
}
```

Or this?

```
if (instance != null)
{
  var x = instance.Property1;
}

if (instance != null)
{
  var y = instance.Property2;
}
```

If the former, does it make a difference if there is other code in between both lines?  In other words, how smart is the compiler/optimizer?

Comment: So many new features, but I'm still waiting for my NON-NULL types. *Sigh*.

Comment: @user2864740 hear hear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler appears to be quite ignorant of this.

The code:

```
var x = instance?.Property1;
var y = instance?.Property2;
```

...compiles as non-optimized to:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  newobj      UserQuery+Class..ctor
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // instance
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // instance
IL_0008:  brtrue.s    IL_000D
IL_000A:  ldnull      
IL_000B:  br.s        IL_0013
IL_000D:  ldloc.0     // instance
IL_000E:  ldfld       UserQuery+Class.Property1
IL_0013:  stloc.1     // x
IL_0014:  ldloc.0     // instance
IL_0015:  brtrue.s    IL_001A
IL_0017:  ldnull      
IL_0018:  br.s        IL_0020
IL_001A:  ldloc.0     // instance
IL_001B:  ldfld       UserQuery+Class.Property2
IL_0020:  stloc.2     // y
IL_0021:  ret         

Class..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_0006:  nop         
IL_0007:  ret
```

...and to optimized as:

```
IL_0000:  newobj      UserQuery+Class..ctor
IL_0005:  dup         
IL_0006:  dup         
IL_0007:  brtrue.s    IL_000C
IL_0009:  pop         
IL_000A:  br.s        IL_0012
IL_000C:  ldfld       UserQuery+Class.Property1
IL_0011:  pop         
IL_0012:  dup         
IL_0013:  brtrue.s    IL_0017
IL_0015:  pop         
IL_0016:  ret         
IL_0017:  ldfld       UserQuery+Class.Property2
IL_001C:  pop         
IL_001D:  ret         

Class..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_0006:  ret
```

Both clearly with two branch checks.

Comment: Hi, this is great! :) off-topic, but I just wonder how do you get the IL in that format?

Comment: @Ian Almost definitely from LINQPad :)

Comment: @Rob hi, thanks for the direction! :D I read the accepted answer on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326571/how-can-i-view-msil-cil-generated-by-c-sharp-compiler-why-is-it-called-assemb and trying to figure out what does it mean by `.text` in the PE file. But if there is an alternative way of looking at the assembly code (as the other answer in the link shows) I would just go and check that. :)

Comment: This is neat, but could you explain the important bits so those who don't understand this exactly can still gain knowledge from it to prove the point of the question?

Comment: @Ian I'm not extremely well versed on the structure of PE files, but I would assume `.text` is simply a section of the file (separate from embedded files, for example). I would just use ILSpy as recommended (or with small snippets, just compile it with LINQPad)

Comment: @Rob I see... Thanks for the direction. I will go and check to play around with it. :)

Comment: @Ian - Yes, this is from LINQPad. Don't leave home without it. I do most of my coding in there now.

Comment: @Enigmativity haha, like it.. :D

Comment: @Ian - The key part to look at is the `brtrue.s`. That's doing the branch on the `null`. Since there are two when the two statements are back-to-back then the compiler isn't very smart.

Comment: Kind of off topic, but couldn't you save one IL line (and file size) by merging the two pops in each branch?  Basically, remove `IL_0009:  pop` and change `IL_000A:  br.s        IL_0012` to `IL_000A:  br.s        IL_0011`

Comment: @Enigmativity, how do you get the ptimized IL from LIQPad?

Comment: @PauloMorgado - Under preferences you can select between optimized and non-optimized. I generally leave it unoptimized as this enabled debugging.

Comment: Thanks, @Enigmativity.  Had never noticed that.

Answer (score 5):

It does two separate If..Else checks for the assignment using null conditional operator in your case. Below is a disassembled sample code

Source Code:

```
public class nulltest
{
    public void test()
    {
        var instance = new testclass();
        var x = instance?.prop1;
        var y = instance?.prop2;
    }
}

public class testclass
{
    public int prop1;
    public int prop2;
}
```

Disassembled code (ILSpy):

```
public class nulltest
{
    public void test()
    {
        testclass testclass = new testclass();
        if (testclass == null)
        {
            int? arg_20_0 = null;
        }
        else
        {
            new int?(testclass.prop1);
        }
        if (testclass == null)
        {
            int? arg_3A_0 = null;
        }
        else
        {
            new int?(testclass.prop2);
        }
    }
}
```

I used `int` as the type of the property but the above should hold true for any other case.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler is rigorous, think about this code.

```
class Tricky
{
    public int Property1
    {
        get
        {
            Program.instance = null;
            return 1;
        }
    }

    public int Property2
    {
        get
        {
            return 2;
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static Tricky instance = new Tricky();

    public static void Main(string[] arg)
    {
        var x = instance?.Property1;
        var y = instance?.Property2;
        //what do you think the values of x,y
    }
}
```

The expected result is : `x == 1, y is null`. But if the compiler optimizes the code using one `if` statement, it throws a `NullReferenceException`. Which means, using one `if` statement, is not a smart optimization, it's not an optimization, because it's WRONG.

Comment: @NelsonRothermel True. However, a compiler shouldn't work under these kind of assumptions, the above code is pure legal from the language view.

Comment: In cases where the left-hand side of the operator could be modified by the right-hand side, it must clearly be re-evaluated, but that wouldn't imply that in places where the compiler could tell that the left-hand side couldn't be modified by evaluating the right (e.g. both it and the right-hand side were field accesses) a compiler couldn't use something like `var temp=instance; if (temp != null) { x=temp.Field1; y=temp.Field2; } else { x=null; y=null; }`