# Does grouping variable types have any effect other than looking neater?

Tags: c#, .net, variables

Just incase my vague description isn't enough to give you the full picture, I mean like this:

```
private bool
    f = true,
    oo = false,
    b,
    a,
    r = false;
```

instead of:

```
private bool f = true;
private bool oo = false;
private bool b;
private bool a;
private bool r = false;
```

Is there any notable advantage or disadvantage in grouping in this way?

Comment: Nope. FYI you can check the IL.

Comment: I strongly suspect both would compile to an identical result.

Comment: To me, _not_ grouping looks way neater.

Comment: Looking neater is just a matter of opinion ;)   And just a side note. In 11 years of C#, I have never seen anyone actually do this in code. You may get yelled at eventually.

Comment: I'm yelling right now. (okay not really)

Comment: Disadavantage - readability, but it is opinion based

Comment: Consider case when your code is under version control. If you need to change type\visibility of single field it would results in changing multiple lines in grouped scenario

Comment: @AleksAndreev that's a very good point.

Comment: I don't think this is opinion based. Despite the fact that the OP included the word "neater" in the title, he's asking if these two declarations have different effects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pasting both of your examples into LINQPad produces identical IL results:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0002:  stloc.0     // f
IL_0003:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0004:  stloc.1     // oo
IL_0005:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0006:  stloc.s     04 // r
IL_0008:  ret
```

So no functional difference, just personal preference.

Comment: Nice! Omg btw, wtf is IL?

Comment: @n00dles [Intermediate Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language).

Comment: Oh, right! That thing! So how do I check performance like you did there? can I do it within VS2017?

Comment: @n00dles I used LINQPad. There are other ways. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326571/how-can-i-view-msil-cil-generated-by-c-sharp-compiler-why-is-it-called-assemb).

Comment: @n00dles VS 2017 includes a command-line utility called [ildasm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ildasm-exe-il-disassembler) (AKA Intermediate Language Disassembler). That said, I can just about guarantee LINQPad is easier. Good utility for testing, regardless.

Answer (score 3):

The code the compiler generates for both code snippets will be identical, so the only remaining concern is maintainability of the resulting code.

As far as maintainability is concerned, the main difference is that the "ungrouped" approach lets you write documentation comments for each individual variable, i.e.

```
/// <summary>Red color component</summary>
private int red;
/// <summary>Green color component</summary>
private int green;
/// <summary>Blue color component</summary>
private int blue;
```

while the "grouped" approach lets you specify a single documentation comment for the entire group:

```
/// <summary>RGB color components</summary>
private int red, green, blue;
```

Neither approach is better than the other; they are just different.

Comment: GA!(Good Answer)(...now redundant) So it's good if you want a blanket comment over a group. That's good to know.

Answer (score 0):

So from what I can gather from the comments and answers; there is no actual performance difference between grouping and not-grouping; grouping being generally 'frowned upon' for various reasons. However, grouping variables does seem like it could be advantageous if you were to group closely-related variables, which would *always* share the same **type**,  **accessibility** and **comment**. This could increase efficiency and workflow performance, but maybe not too a clear degree where it is widely utilised.