# For Each confirmation

Tags: c#, foreach

I believe, I know the answer.  But, trying to get a confirmation.  If, you do something like:

```
foreach (string str in Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(path)) { Console.WriteLine(str); }
```

Instead, of:

```
string[] directoryEntries = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(path);
foreach (string str in directoryEntries) { Console.WriteLine(str); }
```

Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(path), behind the scenes, will only get executed once, correct?  I assume it makes, in this case, the necessary string[] and then does it's looping.  Has too ...

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it will only get executed once. You are correct. How to check it? Here is a snippet you could have write to see it.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var ints = new int[]{0,2,5,8};
    foreach (var i in Print(ints))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}

public static int[] Print(int[] numbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    return numbers;
}
```

Output is:

```
Hello
0
2
5
8
```

[Try this demo online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/u5Vj09)

`Hello` is printed only once!

A better way would have been to use a [debbuger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx) and follow the flow step by step. A more advance way would have been to read the [MSIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326571/how-can-i-view-msil-cil-generated-by-c-sharp-compiler-why-is-it-called-assemb) :)

Comment: Nice and helpful answer

Comment: Huh, that is a smart way to test it out.  Thank you.