# Where are the .NET IL bytes stored in an .NET executable and how does the executable convert them to x86 in runtime?

Tags: .net, windows, reverse-engineering

When I compile a c# code, it compiles into a .NET executable, that only imports _CorExeMain from mscoree.dll, now my questions are :

1. Is _CorExeMain the interpreter that fetches ILs and executes their corresponding x86 code just like VMprotect?
2. Where are the IL bytes actually stored? they seem to be stored in the .text section, but I couldn't find any tool that can find the location that they are stored. Where are they stored?

Comment: See [How can I view MSIL / CIL generated by C# compiler? ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326571/how-can-i-view-msil-cil-generated-by-c-sharp-compiler-why-is-it-called-assemb) and the many links under it.

Comment: @dxiv thanks but that doesn't answer my questions, specially where can i find the IL bytes exactly? i know its probably in text section, but how can i find the location?

Comment: You have [ilspy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy) mentioned there, which is an open source decompiler. Then [other](https://www.ntcore.com/files/dotnetformat.htm) [info](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/anatomy-of-a-net-assembly-pe-headers/) and [tools](https://ntcore.com/?page_id=388). Also, you should clarify the "where" in the question, whether you mean the offset of the .NET section in .text or something else.

Comment: @dxiv yes i have worked with DNspy and ilspy, again i want to know how can i find it myself, meaning when i write a tool that dumps the IL bytes, how can i find them?

Comment: Still not clear what you mean by "IL bytes", whether code alone, or metadata, or anything IL related. Whichever one, you should be able to locate ready-made code for it in the ilspy sources.

Comment: [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy) is open source. Presumably this tool can navigate a managed assembly and locate the IL code. If you want to do the same you could copy that code. If instead you'd much rather understand the platform, get a book like *"CLR via C#"*.

Comment: @dxiv if you open the .NET exe with IDA, it dissambles the "IL bytes", meaning they are just a bunch of bytes that represents ILs that are used in the executable, where can i find them?

Comment: [ECMA-335](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-335/) probably covers that.